# Jquery tablesorter editable columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I have a HTML table which is loaded with tablesorter (motties version). I want to be able to dynamically make content in the table editable AFTER tablesorter has been loaded. I assumed I could just modify the options like so:

```
var widgetOptions = $(table)[0].config.widgetOptions;
widgetOptions.editable_columns = [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13];
widgetOptions.editable_enterToAccept = true;
```

Logging the options to the console appears to have them correctly set:

```
console.log($(table)[0].config.widgetOptions);

editable_autoAccept: true
editable_autoResort: false
editable_columns: (7) [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

However the content is not editable. If i set editable_columns during initialisation then everything works as expected, however I want to do this after initialisation.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

To make a different column editable, you'll need to update the `editable_columns` value then trigger an update. The problem is that once a column is editable, updating doesn't disable already editable columns ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/s6nj8pcu/21/))

```
$(function() {

  var $table = $('#table');

  $('button').click(function() {
    $table[0].config.widgetOptions.editable_columns = [3];
    $table.trigger('update');
  });

  $table.tablesorter({
      theme: 'blue',

      widgets: ['editable'],
      widgetOptions: {
        editable_columns: [0, 1, 2],
        editable_autoAccept: true,
        editable_autoResort: false
      }
    })
    // config event variable new in v2.17.6
    .children('tbody').on('editComplete', 'td', function(event, config) {
      var $this = $(this),
        newContent = $this.text(),
        // there shouldn't be any colspans in the tbody
        cellIndex = this.cellIndex,
        // data-row-index stored in row id
        rowIndex = $this.closest('tr').attr('id');
      /*
      $.post("mysite.php", {
          "row"     : rowIndex,
          "cell"    : cellIndex,
          "content" : newContent
      });
      */
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply mottie, still doesn't work for me. If I add it during initialisation it works perfectly fine, if I try to add it programatically as per your example it doesn't error but also doesn't make the column editable. The versions I have are: TableSorter 2.17.8 and tablesorter Editable Content widget - updated 9/15/2014 (core v2.17.8)

Answer (score 0):

To get this working I had to add the editable widget via the button click and trigger an applywidgets to the table e.g.

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $(table)[0].config.widgets = ["stickyHeaders", "output", "filter" ,"print", "editable"];

    $(table)[0].config.widgetOptions.editable_columns = editableColumns;
    $(table)[0].config.widgetOptions.editable_enterToAccept = true;
    $(table)[0].config.widgetOptions.editable_editComplete = 'editComplete';

    $(table).trigger('applyWidgets');
});
```